# Local assigned constants from a global array item yields garbage. Why?

Tags: swift, constants

I'm unable to assign a value to a constant.

However, I'm able to see the original values from their data array:

```
(lldb) po friendsArray[selectedItemIndex].lastName!
"Umph"
(lldb) po friendsArray[selectedItemIndex].firstName!
"Ronald"
```

But when I assign the current array values to local constants:

```
let fname = friendsArray[selectedItemIndex].firstName!    // "Ronald"
let lname = friendsArray[selectedItemIndex].lastName!     // "Umph"
```

I get garbage:

```
(lldb) po fname
"\xf0\xee\xae\x02\x01"

(lldb) po lname
"KLWR"
```

---

Here's the assets I'm using:

```
enum FriendSelection:Int {
    case selectedFriends = 0
    case allFriends
}
```

```
var friendsArray:[person] = []
```

```
struct person {
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    var image:UIImage?
    var description:String?

    init(firstName:String, lastName:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: What is the definition of friend?

Comment: I've added asset definitions per your request.  A 'friend' is essentially a synonym of 'person'.

Comment: I don't have any error. Are you sure when you po them, their value been assigned? f0ee looks like some raw memory values. String is a struct, I assume they have their space allocated in stack, so they may contain un inited values before inited.